# youtube analytics api, specifying two dimensions

Tags: api, youtube, analytics, dimensions

I'm trying to get a report from the YouTube Analytics API.
I need this report specifying  the country and the dates for an specific video.

This code works:

`dimensions=country&metrics=views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,subscribersGained
sort=-estimatedMinutesWatched&filters=video==VIDEO_ID`

If I specify just the country or day dimension, it works.
If I specify day and country dimensions, it throws a 400 error `Bad request "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."`

This doesn't work:

`dimensions=country,day&
metrics=views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,subscribersGained
sort=-estimatedMinutesWatched&filters=video==VIDEO_ID`

Is there another way to get the data in the format I'm looking for, since seems this query is not supported by the API?

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed. Check the docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports

So you could either 
query country dimension and filter by day
or
query day dimension and filter by country